# passing variable to a table in flask

Tags: python, mysql, sql, flask, datatable

I am following this [video](https://youtu.be/g5BfdCgrc8k?t=236) and everything is working perfectly. The output of a SQL query is saved within a variable that I can call on in another .html page.

so my sql query is:

```
    @app.route('/all_data')
    def all_data():
        customers = db.get_customers()
        for customer in customers:
            var = customers
        return render_template('all_data.html',var=var)
```

When calling this {{var}} in all_data.html page the output is for a long tuple:

```
    ('name','email','comment','gender'),('name','email','comment','gender') etc etc
```

I am looking to put this {{var}} into a table instead?.. I but am hitting a brick wall in finding out how to do this?

any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Flask's default template engine (Jinja2), you can simply use a for loop to iterate over the elements of the collection inside the template. The syntax is:

```
{% for item in items %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

So simply create an HTML table, and add a row for each item in your `var` variable.
IIRC, Jinja tuples act the same as Python's, so you can probably do something along the lines of:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Comment</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for current in var %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ current[0] }}</td>
            <td>{{ current[1] }}</td>
            <td>{{ current[2] }}</td>
            <td>{{ current[3] }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I haven't checked it (as I don't have a Flask project available right now), but if my memory serves me right, that's how I would do it

[Here's a link to an usefull part of Jinja2's documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/)

Also, what is this piece of code for ?

> ```
>     for customer in customers:
>        var = customers
> ```

You're iterating over each element of the list, but your never use the `customer` variable (containing the current element). Instead, you assign the `var` variable to the `customers` list multiple times. Assuming `customers` is a simple Python list, you could remove this loop and simply do `return render_template('all_data.html',var=customers)`